# What's the right way of expressing a desire to meet with someone in the future on the multiple basis?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrase-requests

What's the right way of expressing a desire to meet with someone in the future on the multiple basis (unspecified number of times, but definitely more than once)?

> 1. **We should surely meet again and keep in contact.**
>      → This may mean that I want to meet only one more time and then just keep in contact.
> 2. **We should surely be meeting again and keep in contact**
>      → This will probably mean the same thing as 1.
> 3. **We should surely meet again — and not once — and keep in contact.**
>      → This may mean that I want to meet perhaps only two or three times and then just keep in contact.
> 4. **We should surely meet again in the future on the regular basis and keep in contact.**
>      → This may mean that I almost require a certain level of frequency of future meetings, while I am a far cry from putting such a burden on the person.

So, what should I say here?

Comment: @ClarkKent -  I want to express a desire to continue meeting with a person on a constant basis unlimited number of times, which means I don't want to stop meeting with him or her. However, I don't want to impose any particular frequency levels here like "every other weekend", "once a month", etc. I just want to make it as free and not-pressuring as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like "we should keep in contact and perhaps meet up some more", as it's not necessarily upping the frequency as "on a regular basis" but it's keeping it short and by saying "some more" you're not putting a rough number on the frequency of future meetings; not putting "a burden" on the person but ensuring that you'd like to meet more than once. Also, by saying "perhaps" you're making the person more open to choice.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to say it; I might alter my wording depending on my relationship with the other person.  (I might not use the same language between say, a colleague at work, and a girl I was interested in dating.)

In the general case, I might opt for:

> *We should get together on a regular basis.*

"Get together" implies face-to-face, and "on a regular basis" conveys more than a one-time subsequent meeting.

Also, I'd avoid using the word "surely" in the request; it sounds out of place for some reason.  If you wanted to include an extra qualifier to connote that sentiment, you might try this instead:

> *We should definitely get together on a regular basis.*

which sounds more enthusiastic, but might sound overly desperate, too, if you don't know the other person very well.

If this was more of a request, and you wanted to allow the other person opt out of it without the awkwardness of feeling impolite, you could phrase it in the form of a question:

> *Maybe we could start meeting regularly?*

Comment: I think that by saying "regularly" it seems as if one is pushing the meeting.

Comment: @OllyPrice: That's a good point.  Yes, it could be interpreted that way, depending on the context. I can think of instances where that _wouldn't_ be the case (e.g., in the work environment, if it's someone I know fairly well, and our responsibilities overlap - maybe we run into each other now and again, but it would be better to meet more regularly). However, if it's someone I've just met, "regularly" might indeed sound a bit pushy, and something like "on occasion" or "every now and then" might sound more gentle and appropriate. P.S. I liked what your answer said about "a burden."

Comment: Thank you. So I think we can conclude that you must have a variety of different ways of expressing this, depending on who your talking to and the context. Would you agree?

Comment: @OllyPrice: Agreed; that's one reason I wanted to provide a couple of alternatives. I think all of the suggestions given so far have merit.  Even Kris' simple "let's keep in touch" might work, and be unambiguous in certain contexts.

Answer (score 1):

"Let's keep in touch" will do. It nearly conveys all the things you listed, in an implicit way.  It also sounds better.

Comment: But doesn't it imply just e-mails and telephone conversations, but not necessarily meetings? I really want to convey the idea of meeting in person.

Answer (score 1):

> Let us **always** meet up in future

gives a sense of an endless number of meetings.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps: *We should continue to meet*.

Comment: Or: *Perhaps we should continue to meet.*

Comment: @J.R. that works too :-)